# Form field's controller inside tabs

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have an issue with creating a directive for form's field. The goal that I'm trying to reach is to change some factory data inside the directive's link function when $viewValue is changing. Here is the code:

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-aria@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular-aria.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-animate@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <link data-require="angular-material@0.10.0" data-semver="0.10.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.10.0/angular-material.min.css" />
  <script data-require="angular-material@0.10.0" data-semver="0.10.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.10.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="factory.js"></script>
  <script src="directive.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <md-tabs>
    <md-tab label="TAB1">
      <p>
        Click TAB2. Then click "conslole log" button. You will see the output. Go back to TAB1 and repeat previous actions. Look at the output. What the hell?!
      </p>
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab label="TAB2">
      <form>
        <br>
        <input name="input" ng-model="model.number" test-directive="model">
        <p>
          Model: {{model}}
        </p>
      </form>
      <md-button ng-click="increment()" class="md-primary md-raised">Console log</md-button>
    </md-tab>
  </md-tabs>
</body>

</html>
```

app.js:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'TestFactory',
  function($scope, TestFactory) {
    $scope.model = TestFactory;
    $scope.increment = function() {
      TestFactory.increment();
    }
  }
]);
```

directive.js:

```js
angular.module('plunker').directive('testDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      data: '=testDirective'
    },
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      var n = 1;
      scope.$watch(function() {
        return ctrl.$viewValue
      }, function() {
        console.log(scope.data);
        scope.data.error = !scope.data.error;
        console.log("This function triggered " + n + " times.");
        n++;
      });
    }
  }
})
```

factory.js:

```js
angular.module('plunker').factory('TestFactory', function() {
  Data = {};
  Data.number = 1;
  Data.error = true;
  Data.increment = function() {
    Data.number++;
  }
  return Data
})
```

I created a plunker with simplified copy of my app's structure:
http://plnkr.co/edit/hXFZZ6sM4myGOwMHazd6?p=preview

As I understand, the problem is that every time I switch tabs, a new ctrl is created. Is there any possibility to prevent such weird behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is the watch is being re-registered. You can either check to see if it has already been registered, or unregister it on $desroy.

```
  var deReg = scope.$watch(function(){return ctrl.$viewValue}, function() {
    console.log(scope.data);
    scope.data.error = !scope.data.error;
    console.log("This function triggered " + n + " times.");
    n++;
  });

  elem.on( '$destroy', deReg);
  scope.$on( '$destroy', deReg);
```